# Making deadly conflicts not deadly for the sake of entertainment?

Tags: science-fiction, warfare, super-powers

I am writing a book about people getting superpowers, yada yada yada, I'll spare you the plot.

Anyway, I have teams of superheroes using their powers in combat against other teams in "Leagues" for entertainment for the rest of the masses. These people have deadly powers that are super cool and stuff.

Anyway again, I want to facilitate combat, but I don't want anybody dying. I was thinking of a few things, but I am not sure what could work and what wouldn't.

Here is my question: What rules/technologies/etc. could I use to allow full-scale combat, but allows the players to do it over and over again?

Specifications: I want this to be a combat game, no balls or other objectives than beat the crap out of the guy across from you with your superpowers.

These heroes are not immortal, and each one has a "life-preserving" power, but only to an extent. I want people to be able to use these powers in combat, not to save them after it's over.

I would also prefer this to not be applicable in war per se. I don't want people to be immortal just anywhere, only in the arena for fun.

The superpowers in play include the generic super powers. Main powers I am thinking include Fire, Energy, Water, Super Strength, Flying, Lasers, Cloning. I don't want to list all of them, but solutions for the ones I have said will work for the rest. I hope this helps.

I am not sure if I am asking the right question, but I am looking for help.

Any ideas?

--Thanks!~

Comment: It all depends on what superpowers are in play.

Comment: Alexander asked you to narrow it down to specific superpowers, you seemed to have broadened the question to an infinite extent with "pretty much anything you can think of". Voting to close as too broad until you can [edit] the question to narrow it down. (The superpower I had in mind was "make the author think".)

Comment: Hey man, I am looking for a general solution to a general problem, so it's going to be broad. I have a wide spectrum of powers in play, while I generate even more ideas on that side, I am just stuck on this part. Cool super power by the way. Maybe my MC should have it

Comment: @Jwrecker general solution might not be possible there, but with restrictions, it can be found. Consider Wolverine without blades, Wolverine with blades and Cyclops. Dueling Wolverine without blades can be sport, while with Cyclops all bets are off.

Comment: This is a good point, but I plan to have all heroes have a "life-preserving" ability, hopefully combating someone like Cyclops. This will allow more of a fair fight, and for it to be longer. Still a valid issue though

Comment: I dislike the violent spectacle, but I think the question, in its broadness, invites an interesting set of answers.

Comment: If this "life-preserving" ability can keep participants alive even after the most deadly hits, then here is your answer. If not, "Cyclops" are not eligible to participate in this sport.

Comment: Isn't this just a logical extension of any combat sport? Boxers and MMA fighters have the 'power' to kill each other, but don't. Assuming that in typical superhero fashion the resilience increases in line with destructive effect, then the parallel seems fairly simple.

Comment: Right but again someone who has a life saving ability that is "all or nothing" like a clone or near invulnerability, their powers could make it hard to make them want to stop fighting with finishing them off. Also, fighting someone with your fists takes a certain amount of intent and effort to kill someone, depending on the powers, it could be all but accidental.

Comment: Re "general solution to a general problem" --- SE works on the fundamental principle of *one focused query gets one focused answer*.  I.e., you need to focus on one single problem or concept of worldbuilding in order for this question to remain open. You've got a good general concept going, but it's simply too broad to work here!

Comment: Sure, but I got lots of help already, I feel everyone gets caught up on the question instead of either trying to answer or moving on. World building itself is a very creative open process. I don't know, your rules not mine, and maybe my question is bad, but it seems like it's gotten some answers.

Comment: 1) If the rules of your game severely penalize killing people for the lack of control that demonstrates, that would probably be enough. Every now and then you might have accidental deaths, but it would be in everyone's best interests to avoid them. You might be underestimating how amazingly good humans are at adapting and playing by the rules when it is in their interest to do so. 2) Alternatively, use something a bit like Manton limits, from Worm. The powers are likely already protecting the users of said powers from killing themselves, so maybe those limits extend to other people as well.

Comment: Yes I think that would be good too, but I feel like people might take advantage of that. Someone with relatively weak powers could purposely just kill someone because he doesn't have much to lose.

Answer (score 5):

If it's for entertainment, it is a sport, so treat it like any other sport. Boxing, wrestling, American football could all easily lead to deaths if athletes do not restrain themselves. So have a rule that superheros have to control their powers and temper, and killing or maiming an opponent makes them disqualified for life, and subject to a murder investigation.

You can have superheros matched or ranked into leagues based on their offensive and defensive powers: invincible vs. super-strong, fire-proof vs. fire-shooters, etc.

You can work more detailed rules, from general things like not attacking an opponent who is unconscious or pinned down. to specific things like fire-breathing should not be deployed within 10 yards of the goal (b/c goal can melt and fall on somebody).

Rules will be expanded over time to account for all the various ways superheroes can hurt each other. You can make it a plot point, e.g. supers with certain power keep it hidden or do not use full force of it to avoid a ban, but then one of them says "screw it" and goes all out.

You will also have to have refs on the field that will stop the fight if it gets too dangerous.

Finally, you will need well-defined "win" conditions. If the dude is invincible, the game is not to knock him out, but to kick him out of a 10m circle (without using super-strength), or get the flag that he is defending (without using super-speed or teleport).

Comment: I like this, although I feel with the superpower aspect, it makes law a difficult subject. Also, someone with near-invincibility per-say, it's difficult to have set time that where they lose.  It's a good idea to sort them like that for more finite rules, but I enjoy the idea of variety in a match-up. Thanks for your helpful answer!    P.S. I was looking for a purely combat sport, more similar to boxing, so the goal bit isn't on point, but that's ok, you might have missed it in the question

Comment: I like the "Screw it" part, very interesting idea

Comment: I mentioned it in my question, but I wanted it to not be super objective based, based on the combat, not the objective. It's an interesting idea though.

Answer (score 2):

**Teamwork!**

Allow the non-combatant's "keep alive" power to work on the combatants.  As long as the conflict is small scale, the many inactive super fighters can support and keep the fighters alive.  No one needs to die.  Pleasant times and glorious bloody destructive entertainment for all.

If a situation escalates to war, there won't be enough inactive super fighters to preserve the others, and the dying starts, just as you want.

Comment: I love it! Healer type people standing by, healing after conflict, but in a war the healers can be targets too, making the immortality gone.

Answer (score 1):

**Flag football with bottles of beer instead of flags.**

[image: flag football]

https://www.cfl.ca/2019/03/08/oleary-girls-flag-football-team-changing-game/

In flag football, the players carry on their person representations of themselves.  Instead of knocking a player down, removing a flag from the player signifies that player is incapacitated.

Your battle royale can have something similar.  I envision various sponsors of the fight (all beer makers) equipping each player with a bottle of the sponsor's beverage.  The player carries this beer as he or she sees fit - possibly in a hand, or strapped to the body.  If the bottle breaks the player is done and leaves the field.  If the player drops his bottle or it is stolen from him, he leaves the field.

Victorious players open their unbroken bottles in a spray of foam then holding the bottle above them, pour the beer down into their upturned thirsty mouths.  The crowd goes wild!

Comment: A fight like this would be objectively hilarious.

Comment: And unless the player has a power that prevents inebriation, the game is self-limiting.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like the game we saw played in "The Island" where the players are merely projections of themselves and are limited to the literal abilities? This way, they are protected from one another, can fight to the death and can do it over and over again. You would do this by "tieing" the device to their DNA and using other funky sci-fi fail safes to make what the digital avatar can do be the exact same as what they can do in the real world.

Now you explicitly mentioned superheroes - this type of device would not deter "normal" people from participating. But they wouldn't really stand a chance.

For example:
Say, I (a normal person) wanted to fight and was pair against Thor (enlightened, because lightening is cool) - he would kick the snot out of me, right? I wouldn't have powers, I would be the fat slob I am now because of my DNA and the other "fail-safes" to ensure that it abilities and appearances are transferred across.

Think back to that movie, the only differences were their clothes.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but then I thought that it would be too easy for normal people to participate. It just becomes a video game basically, which kind of detaches the superpowers from the world I guess. It's a great idea, but not what will work for me

Comment: Not if you "tied" it to their DNA so to speak so if say, I (a normal person) wanted to fight and was pair against Thor (enlightened, because lightening is cool) - he would kick the snot out of me, right? I wouldn't have powers, I would be the fat slob I am now because of my DNA and other "fail-safes" to ensure that it abilities and appearances are transferred across. Think back to that movie, the only differences were their clothes.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen it, but interesting idea. Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: You might want to consider revising your answer to include any clarifications you've made in comments.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, still figuring this out